# Explode animation can't replace

Tags: jquery, animation

On my website I am using `hide()` and `show()` animation for a list which appears when the listmenu is changed and it's written like this in the JS file:

```
$('#find').show(1000);
$('#find').hide(1000);
```

Recently I saw something on the jQueryUI website and tried to use it but it didn't work:

```
$('#find').show( "explode", {}, 1000 );
```

My table just becomes visible and invisible without any animation and sometimes it doesn't work either.

[This is the website](http://delimes.ru/) if you need to look to give me advice; the list menu is in the top right, just choose something to watch.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Did you include jQueryUI + the effects plugin in your page? Just checking :)

Answer (score 0):

For me the eplode animation works great.

http://jsfiddle.net/4GbKu/

```
$('.test').hide("explode",{pieces:1}, 1000);
```

for example. Try it out and let me know if that's what you are looking for

Comment: but it doesn't explode,it just hides!